# How to stop foreach loop in Google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I need to generate a docs file from an RSS URL.

```
https://cdn.feedcontrol.net/1830/2857-8L5Ntr0N5l5Xf.xml
```

I have been helped by Tanaike to accomplish that in [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69434026/how-to-get-prototype-data-from-rss-file/69435391).

```
function myFunction1() {
  const url = "https://cdn.feedcontrol.net/1830/2857-8L5Ntr0N5l5Xf.xml";
  const data = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  const root = XmlService.parse(data).getRootElement();
  const ns1 = root.getNamespace();
  const ns2 = XmlService.getNamespace("http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/");
  root.getChild("channel", ns1).getChildren("item", ns1).forEach(e => {
    Drive.Files.insert({title: e.getChild("title", ns1).getValue(), mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS}, HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(e.getChild("encoded", ns2).getValue()).getBlob());
  });
}
```

However, when retrieving all 10 items in RSS, it will be duplicated, because RSS only creates 5 new items.
So I want to stop after creating the DOCs file on the first items.

Please help me!

Comment: Do you want to loop 5 items or 1 item? If 5 items: use `for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {}` instead. If 1 item: you do not need to iterate it `const e = root.getChild("channel", ns1).getChild("item", ns1)`

Comment: @idfurw: Thank you for your reply!
I want it to repeat 5 times.
Sorry for my low knowledge, I don't know how to replace for. I tried something like this but it doesn't work.
 

    `var e = root.getChild("channel", ns1).getChildren("item", ns1);
            for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
              Drive.Files.insert({title: e.getChild("title", ns1).getValue(), "parents": [{'id':folderlocid}], mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS}, HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(e.getChild("encoded", ns2).getValue()).getBlob());
              }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const items = root.getChild("channel", ns1).getChildren("item", ns1);
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  const e = items[i];
  Drive.Files.insert({title: e.getChild("title", ns1).getValue(), "parents": [{'id':folderlocid}], mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS}, HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(e.getChild("encoded", ns2).getValue()).getBlob());
}
```